# Создание одного UserControl с использованием уже созданного UserControl

Tags: c#, gui, wpf

Вопрос не в том, как использовать один в другом, а в том, как мне забиндить размеры внутренних элементов от внешнего, ведь они о нем ничего не знают?
[image]

Внутренние элементы это мой первый UserControl, внешний я строю с их участием. Как забинидить размеры внутренних от внешнего?

Comment: Хм. Расскажите, чего именно вы хотите добиться. Скорее всего, вы пытаетесь изобрести велосипед.

Comment: Эти маленькие контролы будут увеличиваться вместе с внешним, пропорционально. Внешний в свою очередь я хочу забиндить к самому окну.

Comment: если не жестко не устанавливать размеры контролов и правильно выбрать и разместить панели, то они и будут увеличиваться при увеличении окна, например

Comment: Что значит жестко не задать? Вы имеете ввиду задать размеры в % соотношении от другого элемента? Если да, то как это сделать.

Comment: Очень просто: используйте Grid, конечно.

Comment: Вот так?

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>

Comment: Внешний контрол состоит из несколько StacPanel, из 4 если быть точнее. Попробую создавить биндинги динамически из кода, это будет более менее нормальным решением.

Comment: Смотрите: Главный контрол имеет одну StacPanel(вертикальную), которая в свою очередь содержит еще 3, но уже горизонтальных. В этих горизонтальных будут мои userControlы. Хочу чтобы когда внешний контрол менял размер, внутри тоже все оставалось пропорционально

Comment: Тогда замените `StackPanel` на `Grid` с тремя штуками `RowDefinition`, как в примере выше. Вот у вас уже вертикальные размеры вычислились автоматически.

Аналогично поступите и с горизонтальными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу что если в большой UserControl положить Grid, а дочерние элементы расположить в ячейках Grid'а то будет вам то что вы хотите.